# Kubernetes resource descriptors validation issue in metadata string

Tags: kubernetes

During our deployment of the application, Kubernetes is failing to validate the app descriptor file for the application.

```
The request is invalid: patch: Invalid value: "map[metadata:map[annotations:map[deployment.kubernetes.io/revision:<nil> kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"metadata\":{ spec:map[template:map[metadata:map[annotations:map[version:841571000000000] creationTimestamp:<nil>] spec:map[dnsPolicy:<nil> restartPolicy:<nil> schedulerName:<nil>]]] status:<nil>]": cannot convert int64 to string
```

So, during Kubernetes validation of file, it is expanding version value from "841571e9" to "841571000000000" and deployments are failing.

I've tried to replace 'e' with some other character and it's working fine. Looks like Kubernetes descriptor validator is not escaping 'e'.

This problem is observed when the app descriptors have some string value with 'e' in one of its metadata stings.

Is there any permanent fix for this issue?

Comment: Hi @codewarrior, could you clarify how you deploy your app (helm / something else)?

Comment: @mozello, we are doing it from internal deployer tools with GitLab ci pipeline.

Comment: Is there any possibility of a bug in the deployer tool? I've tried without quote 841571e9, with single quote '841571e9' and with double-quote "841571e9" but the same issue persists.

Comment: Where do you add quotes? Could you describe where this variable was created, and what program is used to apply the changes to the Kubernetes cluster (existing tool / kubectl patch / self-written java or go or smth else tool)?